# proving cross products in a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A, B and C be three points which do not lie on the same straight line (i.e. not colinear).

Let **OA = a**, **OB = b** and **OC = c**.  be the position vectors of these three points relative to the origin **O**.

Show that the vector **n= a×b + b×c + c×a** is normal to the plane which passes through the three points.

So far, I know that the **axb** will give me a vector that is perpendicular to a and b and similarly for **bxc** and **cxa**. but how do i prove it for the entire plane?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane is spanned by the two vectors $({\bf b}-{\bf a})$ and $({\bf c}-{\bf a})$. This means that $({\bf b}-{\bf a}) \times ({\bf c}-{\bf a})$ is normal to the plane. By expanding we get

$$({\bf b}-{\bf a}) \times ({\bf c}-{\bf a}) =
{\bf b} \times {\bf c} - {\bf b} \times {\bf a} - {\bf a} \times {\bf c} +
{\bf a} \times {\bf a} = {\bf a} \times {\bf b} + 
{\bf b} \times {\bf c} + 
{\bf c} \times {\bf a}$$

Comment: Ah sweet, thank you very much!....too bad i cant post a picture of my diagram showing the vectors

Answer (score 1):

To prove $n= a×b + b×c + c×a$ is normal to the plane which contains the three points $A,B$ and $C$, it is the same as proving that $n$ is parallel to the normal vector $N$ to the plane. In order to find $N$ follow the steps

1) Construct the vector $u=OB-OA=b-a $

2) Construct the vector $v=OC-OA= c-a$

3) Take the cross product of $u$ and $v$ which gives you $N$.

Once that done check the following step

4) Find $ N \times n $ and should equal $0$.

Comment: Thanks you....i got it out.